# Memory address of ipython magic functions

Tags: python, memory-address, mayavi, ipython-magic

I have been experimenting with the scriptable visualization tool [mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/index.html) from ipython's terminal. 
Mayavi uses the `wx` backend, and therefore I call the magic function just to check the address, then change the gui and check again the address to make sure the change has taken effect (although I know it's a bit useless):

```
In [1]: %gui
Out[1]: <CFunctionType object at 0x03491D50>

In [2]: %gui wx
Out[2]: <wx._core.App; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxPyApp *' at 0x33a8ea8> >

In [3]: %gui
Out[3]: <CFunctionType object at 0x0354AEB8>

In [4]: %gui
Out[4]: <CFunctionType object at 0x0354AF30>
```

The question why are the addresses in 3 and 4 different ?

Comment: You are not specifying  `%gui wx` in 3 and 4 so it makes sense that it is changing, you are creating a new object each call.

Comment: I am calling the function to check if the address has changed after setting the `wx`option, and after this I assume that the address will be the same, unless I change the backend again.

Comment: My question in other words is "why would the address change if I am not changing anything in the behavior of the magic function?"

Comment: No, calling with no arguments removes all GUI support. You are not checking the address of the same object like you were using `%gui wx`, that will return the same object each time

Comment: Ok I didnt know that. You could post the answer by the way

Comment: Ok, I will add the documentation.

Comment: BTW with recent versions of Mayavi, you are likely to have better performance and robustness with Qt/PySide backend than with wx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

For users, enabling GUI event loop integration is simple. You simple use the %gui magic as follows:

%gui [GUINAME]

**With no arguments, %gui removes all GUI support.**

Valid GUINAME arguments are wx, qt, gtk and tk.

Thus, to use wxPython interactively and create a running wx.App object, do:
%gui wx

Comment: I was too lazy to check %gui? in ipython :)